# Is there a comprehensive list of traditional sects sorted by region and principal deity/ies or principal guru with addresses of their branches?

Tags: sects

Is there a comprehensive index of traditional sects in India sorted by region and principal deity/ies or principal guru with addresses of their offices/branches?

I imagine this would be very helpful for people eager to be initiated into the worship of the Ishta of their choice.